Most idiomatic way to mutate multiple similar columns?
I'm generating multiple columns in a mutate() call, all by using a function of 1) an already-existing column and 2) some value which is different for each output column. The following code produces what I want, but it smells:
df <- tibble(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))
df_desired_result <- df |>
  mutate(
    one = str_c(base_string, "1"),
    two = str_c(base_string, "2"),
    three = str_c(base_string, "3")
  )
df_desired_result

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  base_string one   two   three
  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a           a1    a2    a3   
2 b           b1    b2    b3   
3 c           c1    c2    c3   

If there were many other columns, this would be a bad solution.
The best improvement I've come up with is:
df_also_desired_result <- df |>
  expand_grid(
    tibble(
      number_name = c("one", "two", "three"),
      number_string = c("1", "2", "3")
    )
  ) |>
  mutate(final_string = str_c(base_string, number_string)) |>
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = base_string,
    names_from = number_name,
    values_from = final_string
  )
df_also_desired_result

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  base_string one   two   three
  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a           a1    a2    a3   
2 b           b1    b2    b3   
3 c           c1    c2    c3   

But this seems too verbose. Would love any suggestions on a nicer way to do this.

Thanks all for the answers. Edward's is so nice that I previously accepted it, but changed my mind since I really wanted something using the Tidyverse. Today I ended up getting the kind of thing I was originally looking for by creating constant columns for the numbers and then using across():
df <- tibble(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))
df |>
  mutate(
    one = "1", two = "2", three = "3",
    across(one:three, \(x) str_c(base_string, x))
  )

And if the column definitions live in a named vector, you can use !!! to splice the arguments.
column_definitions <- c(one = "1", two = "2", three = "3")
df |>
  mutate(
    !!!column_definitions,
    across(names(column_definitions), \(x) str_c(base_string, x))
  )


Base R solution:
vars <- c("one"=1, "two"=2, "three"=3)
df <- data.frame(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))

df[names(vars)] <- sapply(vars, \(x) paste0(df$base_string, x))
df

  base_string one two three
1           a  a1  a2    a3
2           b  b1  b2    b3
3           c  c1  c2    c3

If your variables and values are in separate vectors, as in your attempted solution, then use this variation:
vars = c("one", "two", "three")
vals = c("1", "2", "3")

df <- data.frame(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))

df[vars] <- sapply(vals, \(x) paste0(df$base_string, x))


Not sure about "idiomatic" part, but bit shorter approach with nested tibbles, controlled by a named vector that is used with purrr::map(), names become column names and function arguments are picked from items.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))

# named vector, column_name = "argument"
col_args <- c(one = "1", two = "2", three = "3") 

# add a tibble column with new columns, controlled by col_args; unnest
df |> 
  mutate(cols = map(col_args, \(x) str_c(base_string, x)) |> bind_cols()) |> 
  unnest(cols)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   base_string one   two   three
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a           a1    a2    a3   
#> 2 b           b1    b2    b3   
#> 3 c           c1    c2    c3

Created on 2024-07-27 with reprex v2.1.0

in base R, you can try outer + paste0 like below
> cbind(df, outer(df$base_string, vars, paste0))
  base_string one two three
1           a  a1  a2    a3
2           b  b1  b2    b3
3           c  c1  c2    c3

data
borrowed from Edward's solution
vars <- c("one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3)
df <- data.frame(base_string = c("a", "b", "c"))


If you prefer tidyverse way, you can try
df %>%
    cross_join(enframe(vars)) %>%
    mutate(value = str_c(base_string, value)) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = name,
        values_from = value
    )

which gives
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  base_string one   two   three
  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a           a1    a2    a3
2 b           b1    b2    b3
3 c           c1    c2    c3

